# Multi-line fprintf() using one element from each array per line

Tags: matlab, printf

I've hit some unexpected behaviour using the fprintf() function in MATLAB. I'm trying to print a multi-line file using the contents of a cell array and a numerical array. I know that I can use the fprintf() function as follows to print out the contents of a cell array:

```
myCellArray = {'one','two','three'};
fprintf('%s\n',myCellArray{:})
```

This results in the following output:

```
one
two
three
```

I can also print out a numerical array as follows:

```
myNumericalArray = [1,2,3];
fprintf('%i\n',myNumericalArray)
```

This results in:

```
1
2
3
```

However, the weird behaviour appears if I try to mix these, as follows:

```
fprintf('%s is %i\n',myCellArray{:},myNumericalArray)
```

This results in:

```
one is 116
wo is 116
hree is 1
```

I *think* this happens because MATLAB tries to print the next entry in `myCellArray` in the place of the `%i`, rather than using the first entry in `myNumericalArray`. This is evident if I type the following:

```
fprintf('%s %s\n',myCellArray{:},myCellArray{:})
```

Which results in:

```
one two
three one
two three
```

...Is there some way to ensure that only one element from each array is used per line?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with your idea. So, I could only think of circumventing this by creating a combined cell array with alternating values from your two initial arrays, see the following code:

```matlab
myCombinedArray = [myCellArray; mat2cell(myNumericalArray, 1, ones(1, numel(myNumericalArray)))];
fprintf('%s is %i\n', myCombinedArray{:})
```

Gives the (I assume) desired output:

```matlab
one is 1
two is 2
three is 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`fprintf(formatSpec,A1,...,An)` will print all the element of `A1` in column order, then all the element of `A2` in column order... and `size(A1)` is not necessarily equal to `size(A2)`.

So in your case the easiest solution is IMO the for loop:

```
for ii = 1:length(myCellArray)
   fprintf('%s is %d\n',myCellArray{ii},myNumericalArray(ii))
end
```

For the small explanation `foo(cell{:})` is similar to the splat operator (python, ruby,...) so matlab will interpret this command as `foo(cell{1},cell{2},...,cell{n})` and this is why your two arguments are not interpreted pair-wise.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the loop solution, only more compact:

```
arrayfun(@(c,n) fprintf('%s is %i\n', c{1}, n), myCellArray, myNumericalArray)
```